Why some addresses (and not others) give errors on nominatim.openstreetmap.org?
I'm using PHP to geocode some addresses with OpenStreetMap. Here's my code:
$addr = 'Brasília/DF, Brasil';
$url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q='.str_replace(' ','+',$addr).'&format=jsonv2&polygon=0&addressdetails=0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = [
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en,pt-BR',
    'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_export($server_output);

Changing the $addr in the first line produces different results. For some, like Copacabana, Rio de Janeiro/RJ, Brasil, it gives me full results. For others, like Brasília/DF, Brasil or Morumbi, São Paulo/SP, Brasil, it gives Invalid HTTP request received, even though these addresses show on their website.
Also tried with R download.file and geocode_OSM functions, same problem.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Don't make your own URL encoding functions, they already exist.

Following the suggestions in the comments, I should have used urlencode in the variable part of the URL, in PHP.
$url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q='.urlencode($addr).'&format=jsonv2&polygon=0&addressdetails=0';

In R, too, geocode_OSM seems to expect the address to be passed through URLencode first (it would be nice if the help explained this).
library(tmaptools)
d = read.csv('my_data.csv',sep='\t')
d$lat = NA
d$lon = NA
nerr = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  print(paste0(i,'/',nrow(d)))
  coord = try(geocode_OSM(URLencode(d$addr[i])))
  if (inherits(coord, "try-error")) {
    nerr = nerr + 1
    print(paste0('ERROR 1: ',d$addr[i]))
  } else {
    if (!is.null(coord)) {
      d$lon[i] = coord$coords[1]
      d$lat[i] = coord$coords[2]
    } else {
      print(paste0('ERROR 2: ',d$addr[i]))
    }
  }
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}

